# How to keep user session active

Tags: windows-server-2003

On Windows Server 2003, how to setup that Remote Desktop Connection never expire for one user?

I tried:
NET USER /expires:never

But it doesn't work, if I close Remote Desktop Connection and then try to connect again, I got again user and password prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net user /expires` configures the expiry date of a user account. It has nothing to do with Remote Desktop sessions. The timeout settings for RDP sessions can be configured via Terminal Services Configuration, in the properties of AD user accounts, or via group policy. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`RDCMan` is widely used to manage multiple `RDPs`. I highly recommend it for operating Remote Desktops.

It has many features, including:

- Keep Current Session Alive
- Auto Login via stored credentials
- Customize Resolution Settings

I hope `RDCMan` will help you to keep session alive in `Windows Server 2003`, as it works perfectly in `Windows Server 2008`.

[Download RDCMan here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21101) or read about it in this [detailed TechNet post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/06/11/3410093.aspx).